# Stylus JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, stylus

I am new in stylus and I have just read the http://bengourley.co.uk/using-stylus but I don't understand where I should add and how to use compile function:

```
function compile(str, path) {
    return stylus(str)
        .define('url', stylus.url({
            paths : [__dirname + "/public"],
            limit : 10000
        }))
        .set('filename', path)
        .set('compress', true)
        .use(nib());
}
```

What else I need to install?
Can somebody show complete example of using stylus?

Thanks in advance!
Srdjan

Comment: Where are you using stylus, in an express app?

Comment: No, I am using stylus with AngularJS. I am looking for solution how to use stylus without sprites.

Comment: There are plugins for grunt, gulp, and broccoli, if you are using any of those build tools. The stylus docs are pretty straight forward though https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html

Comment: I read official documentation and unfortunately I didn't understand how to achieve that. Do you have complete example? Or, can you create new?